# openshift context.xml configuration not serving content outside of war file

Tags: tomcat, openshift

I have edited context.xml from ./tomcat/conf/context.xml to include below alias:

at first, it was working, but then when I redeployed my war file and restarted the gears using the openshift interface. It didn't work. images from a separate path was not loaded anymore. my setup works on my local machine.

What could probably be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please provide details like the relevant bits of the context.xml, stacktrace of errors when it's not working, how did you redeploy the second time around and what's your setup in local machine like?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I have the added the below aliases same on my local machine and openshift (tomcat 7 - Jboss EWS)

 <Context path="/" aliases="/files=/path/to/file">

I restarted my application on openshift and since the configuration was lost. I again edited context.xml to append the above aliases and it didn't worked.